# Adding a variable in an email subject

Tags: python, email, variables, subject

I am trying to run a code that locates specific email in my outlook using the subject line, and then pulling the date/time it was received. When I run the code below it works as expected.

```
import win32com.client
import os
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6).
messages = inbox.Items
messages = messages.Restrict("[Subject] = 'Attached is the report for 20210511'")
for message in list(messages):
    print(message.ReceivedTime)
```

However, if I want to have a variable in the Subject I am not able get the code to work. I've been unsuccessfully trying the following:

```
Date='20210511'
messages = messages.Restrict("[Subject] = 'Attached is the report for {Date}'")
```

Is there a way to get a variable in the subject line?

Comment: You were close. The f-string syntax requires the `f"..."` prefix, so in your case it would be `f"[Subject] = 'Attached is the report for {Date}'"`

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use f string.

```
Date='20210511'
messages = messages.Restrict(f"[Subject] = 'Attached is the report for {Date}'")
```